# Generating documentation for a large(ish) multi-language API

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, multilingual

I'm the author of a fairly sized (and growing) framework. It primarily exposes JavaScript APIs, but also has public APIs in Ruby and a growing CoffeeScript segment. (CoffeeScript will eventually encompass most of the project, but there will always be a significant pure-JavaScript presence.)

Up until now, I've been documenting the JavaScript with [PDoc](https://github.com/tobie/pdoc) and the Ruby with RDoc. Though I've no issues with RDoc, unfortunately PDoc is aging, high-maintenance, and requires a heck of a lot of typing that feels like superfluous clutter. Also, the transition of most of the code to CoffeeScript renders PDoc much less useful than it was.

[Example of the project's current documentation](http://guides.jaxgl.com/api/js/Jax/index.html)

I've experimented with [Rocco](http://rtomayko.github.com/rocco/) in a local branch and it works better than I expected. What's really nice is that it works with *all* my code, from Ruby to Coffee to JS. It's nice to see all the documentation in one place. It's kind of cool to see the source code next to the documentation, too, and this makes it very clear what a particular code segment is actually *doing*.

However, I am a bit worried about the overall structure. Docco/Rocco seems great for niche projects with very few public APIs, but its read-the-entire-project style strikes me as a double-edged sword. Though it's very informative, having to vertically scroll through the files without even a table of contents (not to mention, knowing which file to go to in the first place!) seems like it would make it difficult to actually *find* anything. Also, the default template required some hacking because the list of files was too long to be displayed. Not a huge deal but an annoyance, and a hint that this project may be out of Rocco's league.

I'm now considering [CoffeeDoc](https://github.com/omarkhan/coffeedoc). Judging just by the example, it seems promising, but it is of course Coffee-centric, which brings me back to running 3 separate documentation tools: RDoc, CoffeeDoc and -- what? JSDoc?

I'm not completely adverse to running separate tools for the separate sources, but it becomes hard to reconcile that into a coherent result that doesn't feel like 3 separate Web sites.

So I guess my question is: what tool do you use or suggest? What language(s) does it support? Is it easy to browse, read, and actually *find* a needle in the haystack that is your project? I'm even considering rolling my own tool at this point, except that I can't believe no one else has encountered a problem like this (and I don't really want to waste time if I don't have to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) directly supports [javascript](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#the-javascript-domain). Documentation of Ruby and CoffeeScript is supported through extensions (https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/).

From the website:

The following features are present, work fine and can be seen “in action” in the Python docs:

- Output formats: HTML (including Windows HTML Help), LaTeX (for printable PDF versions), manual pages, plain text
- Extensive cross-references: semantic markup and automatic links for functions, classes, citations, glossary terms and similar pieces of information
- Hierarchical structure: easy definition of a document tree, with automatic links to siblings, parents and children
- Automatic indices: general index as well as a module index
- Code handling: automatic highlighting using the Pygments highlighter
- Extensions: automatic testing of code snippets, inclusion of docstrings from Python modules (API docs), and more

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sphinx looks fairly promising but is apparently only able to auto-doc CoffeeScript. I don't mind manually documenting the JavaScript code since it (eventually) won't comprise much of the project, but was hoping to avoid it for the Ruby stuff. I may come back to this after a while if no other options present themselves.